# Pass data from component to action and saga using React/Redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, frontend

I'm using React with Redux Saga. When I try to execute a Saga Effect in my component with this.props.dispatch({type: CreateActionType.CREATE_ASYNC}); nothing happens, it is not executed.

And when I console.log this.props.data in index.js, it's null

Please let me know if missing necessary info here.

api.js

```
export const create = (params) => {
const dataList = {
    data: {data1: 1, data2: 2,},
    statusCode: 200,
}
    return dataList;
};
```

sagas.js

```
import { put, call, takeEvery , all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { create } from '../api';

import * as CreateActionType from './constants';

export function* createAsync(action) {
    const result = yield call(create, action.params);
    const statusCode = result.statusCode;

    if (statusCode === 200) {
        yield [
            put({ type: CreateActionType.CREATE_SUCCESS, params: result.data }),
        ];
    } else {
        console.warn("createAsync error", result.data);
    }
};

function* WatchCreate() { 
    yield [
        takeEvery(CreateActionType.CREATE_ASYNC, createAsync),
    ]  
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        WatchCreate(),
    ])
}
```

store.js

```
import * as CreateActionType from './constants';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const defaultState = {
    data: null,
}

function CreateStore(state = defaultState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case CreateActionType.CREATE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                createStatus: true,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    CreateStore,
})

export default rootReducer;
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as CreateActionType from './constants';

class CreateNote extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: CreateActionType.CREATE_ASYNC,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return <p>{this.props.data}</p>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {        
    return state.CreateStore;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CreateNote);
```

configstore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from './container/sagas';
import rootReducer from './container/stores';

export default function ConfigureStore() {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

    const store = createStore(rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
}
```

Comment: create a code snippet and share it, you will get more feedback

Comment: it's basic redux saga

Comment: You should debug it. If there's no error messages in the console, add some console.log calls to see what is executed or not.

Comment: the easier you make it for others  the more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what goes wrong, since there's quite a lot of code.

Assuming the saga actually is running, you never do anything with the returned data, which explains why `this.props.data` is null. You can try this.

```
 case CreateActionType.CREATE_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            createStatus: true,
            data: action.params.data,
        };
```

If you are not sure if the sagas are running or not, you should add some logging calls in api.js and sagas.js.

I don't see any reason why the sagas should not work, but you might try to simplify it a bit more. I don't think there's any benefit to yield arrays of effects vs. yielding a single effect.

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(CreateActionType.CREATE_ASYNC, createAsync)
}
```

Comment: @Lid I have data from api.js, and i fixed at index.js with     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({content: nextProps.data});
}. Thank you.

Comment: Why use component state for this? You are using redux. It's much simpler to keep state in redux and just use props in the components.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying this

```
function* WatchCreate() { 
    yield [
        takeEvery(CreateActionType.CREATE_ASYNC, createAsync),
    ]  
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        WatchCreate(),
    ])
}
```

to

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery(CreateActionType.CREATE_ASYNC, createAsync),
    ])
}
```

I find it easier to work on the level of effects (which are synchronously created objects) as much as possible, instead of nested sagas.
Your problem is probably that you call `WatchCreate` and try to use the return value, although it doesn't have one.

Comment: @NguyễnThànhNam

Mh.
I notice you also put your `put` in an array, which is unnecessary.
So you're saying you still have null in your state?
Did you check that all your sagas were called with breakpoints / debugger?
Do you see all expected actions being dispatched in the dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

Your action saga has an argument `createAsync(action)`. You need to pass the data when you are calling the function, like this `takeEvery(createActionType.CREATE_ASYNC, createAsync, action)`. Take this example below.

```js
import { call, put, SagaReturnType, takeLatest } from '@redux-saga/core/effects'
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import * as ActionCreators from './actionCreators'
import * as ActionTypes from './actionTypes'

type apiResponse = SagaReturnType<typeof deleteUser>

const deleteUser = async (userId: string): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    return axios.delete(`localhost:8081/users/${userId}`)
}

function* deleteUserSaga(user: User) {
    try {
        if (user.userId) {
            const response: apiResponse = yield call(deleteUser, user.userId)

            if (response.status === 200) {
                put(ActionCreators.deleteSuccess(user))
            }

            throw new Error('User delete unsuccessful')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        put(ActionCreators.deleteError(err))
    }
}

// eslint-disable-next-line
export default function* DeleteUserWatcher(user: User) {
    yield takeLatest(ActionTypes.DELETE_BEGIN, deleteUserSaga, user)
}
```